# actuator/shutdown not killing Java process

Tags: spring-boot

Recently I have upgraded spring boot version to 2.6.7 from 2.3.11 Release

I am using management.server.port as 8080 when call curl post https://localhost:8080/actuator/shutdown then my application stopped but still Java PID running why?

Answer (score 0):

What port is the PID listening on?

Perhaps its a Java process that is not related to the Spring Boot application.

To view process id and ports assigned to it this command should do the trick if using Linux

```
lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN
```

Do you still see 8080 (LISTEN) ?

Comment: No it's not LISTEN
After i call actuator/shutdown not seen any port LISTEN  but still PID processing

Comment: Application stopped successfully and again started with new PID but old PID also able to see with same application.    ps -ef | grep java